# Typescript Flexible 'thunked' function

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a 'thunked' method:

```
createToDoMethodWithConversion<T1,T2>(getOutputOfTypeA: (val1: T1, val2: T2) => TA): (val1: T1, val2: T2) => TB {
     return (val1: T1, val2: T2) => {
       const item: TA = getOutputOfTypeA(val1, val2);
       return this.doSeriousConversionBusiness(item); // convert to TB
     };
}
```

How can I make flexible enough to do something like this:

```
const newMethod: (val1: T1, val2: T2, val3: T3) => TB
  = createToDoMethodWithConversion<T1,T2,T3>(getX: (val1: T1, val2: T2, val3: T3) => TA)
```

Or this:

```
const newMethod: (val1: T1, val2: T2, val3: T3, val4: T4) => TB
  = createToDoMethodWithConversion<T1,T2,T3,T4>(getX: (val1: T1, val2: T2, val3: T3, val4: T4) => TA)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting in TypeScript 3.0, you can use [tuple types in rest/spread positions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions).  This allows you to have a single generic type parameter to represent the list of arguments to a function:

```
createToDoMethodWithConversion<T extends any[]>(
  getOutputOfTypeA: (...val: T) => TA
): (...vals: T) => TB {
  return (...vals: T) => {
    const item: TA = getOutputOfTypeA(...vals);
    return this.doSeriousConversionBusiness(item); // convert to TB
  };
}
```

Note the use of rest arguments in function definitions and the analogous spread arguments in function calls.  Let's see if it works:

```
const x = new Foo(); // class containing createToDoMethodWithConversion method
declare const f3: (x: string, y: number, z: boolean) => TA;
const newF3 = x.createToDoMethodWithConversion(f3) // (x: string, y: number, z: boolean) => TB;
declare const f4: (x: string, y: number, z: boolean, w?: RegExp) => TA;
const newF4 = x.createToDoMethodWithConversion(f4) // (x: string, y: number, z: boolean, w?: RegExp) => TB;
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: you can even do this:

    createToDoMethodWithConversion<[string, number, boolean]>(f3: (a:string, b:number, c: boolean) => {// .. do}